# R: Loop pairs of columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, loops, plot

Is it possible to plot pairs of columns in a single plot with a loop? For example, if I have a data frame of time series with 10 columns  (x1, x2.. x10), I would like to create 5 plots: 1st plot will display x1 and x2, the 2nd plot would display x3 and x4 and so on.

Any plotting method would be useful, (zoo, lattice, ggplot2).

I got stuck at creating a loop to plot a single variable:

```
set.seed(1)

x<- data.frame(replicate(10,rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1)))
cols <- seq(1,10) 

library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(x)

for (i in cols) {
plot(z[,i], screen = 1)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you ant to plot both columns against the index or against each other?

Answer (score 1):

How about this with `ggplot2` and `reshape2`:

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
m<-melt(matrix(z,10))
m$facet<-cut(m$Var2,c(0,2,4,6,8,10))
ggplot(m)+geom_line(aes(x=Var1,y=value,group=Var2,color=factor(Var2)))+facet_wrap(~ facet)
```

[image]

Comment: There's only 9 plots because z from your code only has 9 cols.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in a single line without a loop like this where the `col` argument specifies that the odd series are black and the even are red.  Note that `z` in the question has 9 columns (since the first column in `x` is the time index) so we have used a 10 column `z` below instead which was likely what was intended.

```
library(zoo)
# test data
set.seed(123); z <- zoo(matrix(rnorm(250), 25)); colnames(z) <- make.names(1:10)

plot(z, screen = rep(colnames(z)[c(TRUE, FALSE)], each = 2), col = 1:2)
```

The output is shown below.  To produce a single column add the argument `nc=1` or to produce a lattice plot replace `plot` with `xyplot`.

[image]

ADDED: lattice solution.

Answer (score 0):

like this? Although I am not clear how you want to plot it.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,5))
for (i in seq(1,10,by=2)){

  plot(x[,i],x[,i+1])
}
```